# How to prevent XSS vulnerability in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, security

When I directly write `https://example.com/?trigger=*/</script><script>alert(1)</script>` in url bar, it prompts the alert box.

How to fix this in a wordpress site?

I've tried some plugins like security headers, html purifier etc, but no success.

How to prevent these kind of vulnerabilities?

Comment: How is the `trigger`-parameter handled in the code? I don't get that behavior on a standard WP-install. To prevent XSS, you need to filter the variable before it's sent to the client, just like you need to do with any user supplied data (WP or no WP). Example: `htmlentities()`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson trigger was not tried to handle in the code. i just write in the URL and it gives the alertbox

Comment: Hm. I can't reproduce that behavior. Do you have any plugin that might use the variable wrong (unescaped)?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson No such kind of any plugin

Comment: If you see an alert, then some piece of code _must_ send the raw contents of the `trigger`-parameter to the client. I've tested on multiple different WP sites (in different versions) I have built and can't reproduce this, so it doesn't seem to be in the core.

Comment: I think this is a question for [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This plugin encode the following signs and then Remove some XSS signs from the URL:

[Prevent XSS Vulnerability](https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-xss-vulnerability/)

You can Encodes or Block such type of Entities. You can also add Entities in Comma Separated Form which you do not want to be blocked/remove in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the free version of the [Wordfence Security Plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). I tried your link on my site: [`https://www.majlovesreg.one/?trigger=*/</script><script>alert(1)</script>`](https://www.majlovesreg.one/?trigger=*/%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert(1)%3C/script%3E) and no browser alert was created.

Looks like security plug-ins can do the job. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to prevent XSS on your website, you can block certain inputs such as special characters (<,>,/,) as well as only allow public users to input information when prompted to. Here is a great article to read to increase your knowledge, because sometimes you can't always find a plugin to fix your issue :)

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

p.s It also lists many more prevention methods.